RUST image error when curl it, but will work correctly when running it with ```Cargo run```
i've made a small and simple RUST RESTful server, Im encountering an issue when trying to curl to the docker image version of the program:  curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer, and when trying to surf directly to 127.0.0.0:3000 ill get This site can’t be reached error.
When trying to the run the server using Cargo run the program returns the correct
Here is my main.rs file:
use axum::{extract::Query, response::Html, routing::get, Router};
use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::net::SocketAddr;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let app = Router::new()
        .route("/", get(handler))
        .route("/test", get(handler2));

    let addr = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000));
    println!("listening on {}", addr);
    axum::Server::bind(&addr)
        .serve(app.into_make_service())
        .await
        .unwrap();
}

// `Deserialize` need be implemented to use with `Query` extractor.
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct RangeParameters {
    start: usize,
    end: usize,
}

async fn handler(Query(range): Query<RangeParameters>) -> Html<String> {
    // Generate a random number in range parsed from query.
    let random_number = thread_rng().gen_range(range.start..range.end);

    // Send response in html format.
    Html(format!("<h1>Random Number: {}</h1>", random_number))

}

// `Deserialize` needs to be implemented to use with `Query` extractor.
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct UserParameters {
    start: usize,
    end: usize,
    username: String, // Add a string field
}

async fn handler2(Query(user_detailes): Query<UserParameters>) -> Html<String> {
    // Generate a random number in range parsed from query.
    //let random_number = thread_rng().gen_range(range.start..range.end);

    // Send response in html format.
    Html(format!("<h1>User start: {}, User end: {}, Username is???: {}</h1>", user_detailes.start, user_detailes.end,user_detailes.username))

}


My Cargo.toml and Dockerfile :
[package]
name = "rust-image"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
axum = "0.5"
rand = "0.8"
serde = { version = "1", features = ["derive"] }
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }


AND
ARG RUST_VERSION=1.70.0
ARG APP_NAME=rust-image

FROM rust:${RUST_VERSION}-alpine AS build

RUN apk add --no-cache clang lld musl-dev git

WORKDIR /app
COPY src /app/src
COPY Cargo.toml /app

ARG APP_NAME


RUN cargo build --release && \
    cp ./target/release/rust-image /bin/server


FROM alpine:3.18 AS final


ARG UID=10001
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    appuser
USER appuser

COPY --from=build /bin/server /bin/

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["/bin/server"] 

Im using the following command to run the Docker image - docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 rust-image1 
UPDATE -
Needed to bind the server to 0.0.0.0 and not to 127.0.0.1 (Credit in the comments)

Don’t bind to 127.0.0.1. Bind to 0.0.0.0

@DanielA.White thank you so much, working :)
